# Can not find class during Puppet apply

Tags: puppet

My puppet structure is as follows

```
/puppet
    /manifests
        /nodes
            redis.pp
        site.pp
    /modules
```

The site.pp resembles

```
class base {
  include ml-basefw
  include ml-users
  include ml-filelimits
  include repoforge
  include epel

class { 'ml-yumrepo':
  base_url => "http://${puppet_server}/yumrepo"
 }
}
import 'nodes/*.pp'

node default {
   include base
}
```

When I run

```
puppet apply  --modulepath=/puppet/modules:/puppet/manifests --noop --debug /puppet/manifests/nodes/redis.pp
```

I receive

```
Error: Could not find class base for redis-1.test.ml.com on node redis-1.test.ml.com
```

Is there something non-standard about my file layout that precludes me from using apply?

I am not the maintainer of the puppet module so I am not able to alter the file structure or layout.

There are numerous related questions but I wasn't able to relate them to the problem that I am having.

Edit1 : Adding redis.pp

```
node /^redis-\d+(.stage)?(.test)?(.aws)?.ml.com$/ {
include base
include epel

class { 'redis':
package_ensure => '2.8.15-1.el6.remi',
service_ensure => 'running',
conf_bind => '0.0.0.0',
conf_port => '6379',
}

firewall { '176 allow port 6379 for redis traffic':
chain => 'INPUT',
state => ['NEW'],
dport => '6379',
proto => 'tcp',
action => 'accept'
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly show the content of `redis.pp` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you run puppet apply against your site.pp file instead? You probably don't have a node definition in your redis.pp file (nor should you).

Comment: Not having a `node` definition is actually typical for `puppet apply`. You just write a manifest that is specific to the local machine and apply that directly.

Comment: ...but yes, applying `site.pp` seems to be what is expected in this setup.

Answer (score 2):

This does in fact look a little messy and convoluted.

What you want is

- an actual `base` module
- defining `class base` in `/puppet/modules/base/manifests/init.pp`

You should also loose the `import` statement by arranging your manifests better. If your version of Puppet is recent enough (I think `3.6`+), just see [the docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_import.html).

Comment: Like I said, I can't alter the contents or structure very much. I'm trying to get what has been designed for the enterprise to work on my local vm's. We seem to have no issue with the structure in production/staging.

Comment: @bearrito and I completely misread that. Sorry for not being too helpful. I upvoted @tthayer on account of the suggestion to apply `site.pp` instead of `redis.pp`.

Comment: I'd be happy to create an extraneous file that emulates the correct functionality, something that does not force any structural changes or would affect other workflows, that just allows me to get it working locally (using apply without puppetserver)

Comment: In its current form, it looks hardly salvageable from here, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

fist of all, puppet have the entry manifest file.
in master mode, the entry is site.pp and puppet deprated deprecated it from version 3.5, it started auto imported all manifest files in specified directory.
in apply mode, the entry is specified file in your command.

so it works fine in your production environment, puppet master read site.pp(contains class base) and import nodes/*.pp(redis.pp, contains node definition). but when you use "puppet apply /puppet/manifests/nodes/redis.pp", puppet just read redis.pp, no anyone tell puppet where the base class is.